# Waitlist not working after event limit is increased

Tags: civievent

Due to COVID we had limited our events to 20. Our September, 2021 event is oversubscribed with 8 on the waitlist.

We recently increased the limit to 28 and I expected that all the folks on the waitlist would be notified but none of them were. I guess a change in the limit after initiating the event does not get communicated to the waitlist.

Another waitlist question: our events have "Pay Now" and "Pay Later" options. It seems to me that the event limit = "Pay Now" + "Pay Later" at which point Waitlist kicks in. I would like the limit to be only the "Pay Now" folks. Is there someway I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue about increasing the waitlist limit. Check that the relevant scheduled job is running: `Job.process_participant`. This handles processing the waitlist participants. Read more in the [User Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_process_participant).

You'll also need to make sure that you have a [cron job](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#cron) that triggers the scheduled jobs (or you can run it manually).